# Grabbing info from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to grab the username from this JSON in PHP:

```
["{\"account\":{\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"hey\",\"info\":{\"ip\":\"193.90.12.119\",\"proxyMethod\":\"TOR\",\"time\":\"2018-03-17 05:32:58\"}}}"]
```

The JSON is stored in a file. While I have the code down to grab the JSON from the file. I'm having quite the issue with grabbing the username.

What I have right now:

```
<?php
$file = ('/var/www/html/account/generator/accounts.json');
$accountJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);


echo count($accountJson);
echo $accountJson[0];

echo 'done';
?>
```

But when I attempt to grab the username by doing

```
echo $acountJson[0]['account'];
```

it only echos `{`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where did that file come from? It looks like it contains an array of length one whose only member is a JSON string (which will itself need to be `json_decode()`d). If you control the creation of that file and you can fix its formatting you'll have a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case the content of `$accountJson[0]` is a String, you have to decode this as well, so if you use this following code should work:

```
<?php
  $file = ('/Users/cesar/Sites/diversos/teste/accounts.json');
  $accountJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

  $stringData = $accountJson[0];

  $data = json_decode($stringData);

  echo $data->account->username;
?>
```

Here I tested and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo $acountJson[0]['account'];` try this `echo $accountJson[0][account][username];`

Here is my JSON File:

```
[
  {
    "account":
    {
      "username": "test",
      "password": "hey",
      "info":
      {
        "ip": "193.90.12.119",
        "proxyMethod": "TOR",
        "time": "2018-03-17 05:32:58"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
$file = ('accounts.json');
$accountJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

echo $accountJson[0][account][username];


echo '<br>done';
```

Hope This helps.